# Start Loading Form only One time and not appear again till Application is restart

Tags: c#

I'm coding with C# and i'm using a loading form (SplashScreen) to start my application and once loaded you get access to login form.
So after you login you get access to Dashboard Form, and in Dashboard From there is button to logout. 
So when you click on Logout it show login form again in order to login again but my issue is before login form appears it goes directly to loading form (SplashScreen) first and after it come to login. I want Loading Form (SplashScreen) appears only once at the beginning when the application start for first time and not come back again till the application is restart.

Below my Code :

// Login Form

```
public Login_Form()
{
  Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartFrom));
  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  InitializeComponent();
  t.Abort();       
}

public void StartFrom()
{
   Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
}
```

// Logout From

```
private void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Hide();

  Login_From fLogin = new Login_From();
  if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     DashBoardForm view = new DashBoardForm();
     view.ShowDialog();
  }
  else
  {
     Application.Exit();
  }
}
```

//Program cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         //Application.Run(new Login_From());

         Login_From fLogin = new Login_From();
         if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             Application.Run(new DashBoardForm());
         }

         else 
         {
             Application.Exit();
         }


    }
}
```

Comment: Put the code for showing the splash in `Program.cs` in the `Main` method.

Comment: Check Now I've updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

First run the splash screen form the program.cs

//Program cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

         frmSplashScreen splash = new frmSplashScreen();
         splash.Show();
    }
}
```

Then from the splash screen, show the login form.

//Splash

```
public frmSplashScreen()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Login_From fLogin = new Login_From();
    fLogin.Show();
}
```

When logging out, just create a new login form and show it.

// Logout From

```
private void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    Login_From fLogin = new Login_From();
    this.Close();
    fLogin.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments inline for clarity.

**Main Method**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    new SplashScreenUsingVBFramework().Run(args);
}
```

**Inherit WindowsFormsApplicationBase**

```
// We need to add Microsoft.VisualBasic reference for type 
// WindowsFormsApplicationBase.

class SplashScreenUsingVBFramework : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        base.OnCreateSplashScreen();
        // You can replace the Splash2 screen to yours.
        this.SplashScreen = new CSWinFormSplashScreen.SplashScreen2();
    }
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        base.OnCreateMainForm();

        // Here you can specify the MainForm you want to start.
        Login_From fLogin = new Login_From();
        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new DashBoardForm());
        }
        else 
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have borrowed and modify the code from a sample [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinFormSplashScreen-4a97fc0a). It even has a splash screen sample which fades out if you are interested.